# Web.Config file missing from ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: database-connection, connection-string, asp.net-core-6.0

The `web.config` file is missing and I have no idea where to place my connection string.

This is my `DbContext` code:

```
namespace Patient_Enrollment.Repo
{
    public partial class Contxt : DbContext
    {
        public Contxt() : base("name= EnrollmentEntity")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my Home controller where I use the `Contxt`:

```
 public static Contxt GetContxt()
 {
     return new Contxt();
 }
```

Comment: Missing?  Did you accidentally delete it?  Can you pull a copy from your live/dev server and add it back to the project?

If not, you could right click the project, add > web configuration file.  Then add your <connectionStrings> section in <configuration>

Comment: ASP.NET Core apps typically use `appSettings.json` these days - `web.config` has been more or less deprecated

Comment: @KevinM am used to asp.net core 5 and now im trying to create a web application on asp.net 6.0 and it came without web.config file and when i add it myself it gives me an error that it cannot find a connection string with "EnrollmentEntity" [ (name= EnrollmentEntity)]

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObwWK.png)

In Visual Studio 2017, click mouse right button in Project in Solution Explorer -> Add -> New Item -> Search for "config" -> Add Web Configuration File. This will add web.config in your project with default stuff.